# How to use math function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math

How to execute this code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(1,9, 0.5)
k = math.cos(x)
print(x)
```

I got an error like this:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html

Answer (score 4):

So this is happening because `math.cos` doesn't accept numpy arrays larger than size 1. That's why if you had a np array of size 1, your approach would still work.

A simpler way you can achieve the result is to use `np.cos(x)` directly:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,9, 0.5)
k = np.cos(x)
print(x)
print(k)
```

If you have to use the math module, you can try iterating through the array and applying `math.cos` to each member of the array:

```
import numpy as np 
import math 

x = np.arange(1,9,0.5) 
for item in x:
    k = math.cos(item) 
    print(k) # or add to a new array/list
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this?

```
import numpy as np 
import math 
x = np.arange(1,9, 0.5) 
for ang in x:
    k = math.cos(ang) 
    print(k)
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass ndarray (returned by [arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html?highlight=arange)) to a function, which expects just real number. Use [np.cos](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html?highlight=cos#numpy.cos) instead.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want `pure-Python`:**

You can use `math.fun` in `map` like below:

```
import math
x = range(1,9)
print(list(map(math.cos, x)))
```

Output:

```
[0.5403023058681398, -0.4161468365471424, -0.9899924966004454, -0.6536436208636119, 0.2836621854632263, 0.9601702866503661, 0.7539022543433046, -0.14550003380861354]
```